# single positional indexer is out-of-bounds filter a list by using function which checks for 2nd column of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

pb_count has the following data frame

```
LOCATION  107

LENGTH    81

LANES     92
```

drop_columns has the following value:

```
Index(['LOCATION','LENGTH', 'LANES'], dtype='object')
```

I wrote the following function:

```
def compare(row):
    '''checks if the count of non recorded data is greater than equal to 100'''
    if (pb_count[1][pb_count[0]==row]).iloc[0] >=100:
        return False
    else:
        return True
drop_columns_temp = list(filter(compare,drop_columns))
```

I am getting

> IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

for the following code i am getting value as 92.

```
(pb_count[1][pb_count[0]=='LANES']).iloc[0]
```

I am trying to get the first column values which have second column value <100

Comment: Got solution friends, what I showed here is sample data, but in the data which I am trying. There is a mismatch between  values in list and column names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got solution friends, what I showed here is sample data, but in the data which I am trying, There is a mismatch between values in list and column names